# Is there a way to detect whether the browser supports CSS3 animations or not?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm working on the task of web animations using CSS3, my reference is from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/07/splash-and-coming-soon-page-effects-with-css3/, but there is a problem, not all browsers support CSS3 animations, is there a way to know the browser support or not support CSS3 animations?I want to detect it using Javascript/jQuery, PHP, or CSS itself. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com), it adds CSS classes to HTML that allow you to tell if specific features are available.

Answer (score 2):

Found a short JS approach here.

[Detecting_CSS_animation_support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_animations/Detecting_CSS_animation_support)

Comment: Great! Thanks Mathew, this was just what I was looking for. Don't want to include the whole Modernizr library just for one detection.